Locate specific text for an element when specific text is partially variable (selenium Java)
For following element I need to locate the counts for Requeues, App Exits and Greets Started.
Further I will need to verify the counts for for each events.
<div _ngcontent-ome-c213="" class="counts"> 0 Requeues<br _ngcontent-ome-c213=""> 0 App Exits<br _ngcontent-ome-c213=""> 2 Greets Started </div>

Tried:
public void verifySessionMetricsWasGenerated(String metrics, int count) {
        assertThat(findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'counts') and contains(text(), '" + metrics + "')]")))
                .as("Did not find expected number of metrics '" + metrics + "' " + SpecContext.examSession())
                .hasSize(count);

Got:
Expected size: 1 but was: 0 in:
[]
Stack Trace:
java.lang.AssertionError: [Did not find expected number of metrics 'Greets Started' 


I think the easier way to approach this problem is to call a method that returns all 3 metrics, then assert each metric in the test.
To return all metrics, we need a class that can hold the 3 values.
Metrics.java
public class Metrics
{
    public String Requeues;
    public String AppExits;
    public String GreetsStarted;

    public Metrics(String requeues, String appExits, String greetsStarted) {
        Requeues = requeues;
        AppExits = appExits;
        GreetsStarted = greetsStarted;
    }
}

Then we need a method to return an instance of Metrics that contains the 3 values,
public static Metrics getMetrics() {
    String counts = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.counts")).getText();
    String[] countStrings = counts.split("\\n");

    return new Metrics(countStrings[0].split(" ")[0], countStrings[1].split(" ")[0], countStrings[2].split(" ")[0]);
}

Then we have the test itself,
String expectedRequeues = "0";
String expectedAppExits = "0";
String expectedGreetsStarted = "2";

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

Metrics metrics = getMetrics();
Assert.assertEquals(metrics.Requeues, expectedRequeues, "Verify requeues");
Assert.assertEquals(metrics.AppExits, expectedAppExits, "Verify app exits");
Assert.assertEquals(metrics.GreetsStarted, expectedGreetsStarted, "Verify greets started");


If metrics are always in the shown order they can be obtained with
String xpathExpression = "//div[@class='counts']"
String[] counts = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression))
    .getText()
    .split("([^0-9]+){1,}");

for (String c : counts) {
    System.out.println("Count: " + c);
}

Result
Count: 11
Count: 322
Count: 217

